# How to convert NativeScript web Application to mobile application

Tags: angularjs, angular, cross-platform, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In Nativescript documentation, it is been said that it allows you to build mobile apps using the same framework—and in some cases the same code—that you use to build Angular 2 web apps. But when I try to build same code for mobile application, it throws me the following error:

"No project found at or above 'C:\Users\GSC-30121\Desktop\Demo\Template\SB-Admin-
BS4-Angular-2' and neither was a --path specified."

My question is if it is possible to convert web code to mobile code or vice versa, how to do it? There's not a single example available on internet to do so. [Have a look at this snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaarQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

In nativescript you cannot convert web directly into app.
But there are some solution to do that
Try the below [link](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ng2-magic)
https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ng2-magic